# Creating project with angular-cli takes a long time

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli to scaffold a new Angular2 project with `ng new project_name`. It takes a long time to complete, as it downloads all dependencies each time `ng new` is run. Is there a way to create subsequent new projects without having to re-download all the dependencies?

Answer (score 36):

You can use `ng new project_name --skip-install` or `ng init project_name --skip-install` to not download all the additional packages right away. You could then copy the node_modules directory from an existing project template, and finally do an `npm install` or `yarn install` to make sure everything is happy, depending on your package manager.

Previous versions use `ng new project_name --skip-npm` or `ng init project_name --skip-npm`

Comment: Hi Filldes , Thanks for your reply...... I am facing one problems here 1) After running new new project_name --skip-npm.... Which working fine but after copying the node_modules and running npm install.... Again it is taking time .... What actually i want after creating project, Project should directly run by ng serve command..

Comment: @stackinfostack if you're confident that all the libraries are there and up-to-date, you should be able to skip the `npm install` and just run `ng serve`.

Comment: Got this message: The option '--skip-npm' is not registered with the new command. Run `ng new --help` for a list of supported options.

Comment: @Julia the command option might've changed in recent release. I'll check

Comment: Just run **ng new myproject** with the latest version of @angular/cli. The result is: "added 1457 projects in 287.624 seconds".. This is just insane.. And it does not seem to cache anything but does this 287 seconds insanity for every new project! Just compare this with creating a new project with Maven..

Answer (score 23):

It is by far faster to use:

```
ng new myProject --skip-install=true
cd myProject
npm install
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using latest `angular-cli` tool then use the following command.

```
$ ng new <project name> --skip-install=true
```

This will avoid npm to install all the required dependencies.

Comment: but to run the project you need dependencies so at the end you have to install them and its gonna take same time as there whole lot of them

Answer (score 3):

Run following two commands -
`ng new project_name --skip-npm` //Only create project structure.
`npm install` //To install all necessary packages.

Comment: --skip-npm not working.  --skip-install=true worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create new project `ng new example`

Wait a few seconds and cancel the installation of packages using `ctrl+c` then `cd example`

Now run `npm install`

Answer (score -5):

Create a new angular project ng new my-dream-application and press enter. When it is getting stuck, press the enter button twice or thrice then it completes smoothly.

Comment: You are merely redescribing the problem. The user followed these steps and encountered the issue in the 1st place.